# Generate google-services.json for Android GoogleSignIn when not using Firebase

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I am trying to enable GoogleSignin in my React Native app for Android, which does not use Firebase. However, when I go through the "Configure a Project" process in the Google SignIn for Android console (found here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) to generate a `google-services.json` file, I instead get a `credentials.json` file.

The schemas are different and I already tried renaming the `credentials.json` to `google-services.json` but to no avail. Furthermore, when I click the "Configure a Project" button again, I now get a pop up saying "Something went wrong. Please try again later." In my browser console I see that it is a 409 error.

How can I generate the `google-services.json` file for a non Firebase project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this without Firebase. I was under the impression that if I wasn't using a Firebase database that it wouldn't be a good idea to register my app there. But, it seems like Firebase and Google have partnered over this so I went ahead and did it anyway and got the `google-services.json` that I needed (and still not using Firebase for my db).